# How to enable language selection display using cpack, cmake and NSIS?

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I am using cpack, cmake and NSIS to create an installer for my application. The result does not display the language selection options as default and there is no cpack nsis flag to enable it (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/nsis.html).

It seems there should be a `!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY` inside the `.onInit` function of the nsi project configuration. But I can't find a way to force that macro inside the correct function via cpack/cmake commands.

Comment: Does cpack even support multiple languages in NSIS installers?

Comment: I thought it should support, because it is currently creating an installer in Portuguese, which is my system language.